# Count the number of occurrences of "NZ" and "O" inside the txt file.

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match and count out the number of occurrences of NZ and O inside a txt file...

```
Import re 
pattern = re.compile(r'NZ')
with open ('scratch_1.txt','r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    matches = pattern.finditer(contents)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Above is my current code and this matches all the 'NZ.' What I am trying to get to is match all 'NZ' and 'O' and counting the number of appearances. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the pattern to look for either NZ or O:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'NZ|O')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to do:

```
n1 = contents.count('NZ')
n2 = contents.count('O')
result = n1+n2
```

If you really want the regex, I think the pattern `NZ|O` should work.

Comment: Why make `NZ` a capturing group? It's static.

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-capturing group with an alternation (`|`, the pipe character) between `NZ` and `O`. And I would use `re.findall` wrapped in `len` since `re.findall` returns a `list` of the occurrences.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'HellO world! NZO NZ O NZ NZNZNZN O'
>>> len(re.findall(r'(?:NZ|O)', text))
10
```

Tested it here: https://regexr.com/44ms6